# Passing a boolean type into a bit parameter type in C# and MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a C# method that accepts a clientId (int) and hasPaid (boolean) that represents if the client has paid or not. The MS SQL Server stored procedure expects a BIT value (1 or 0) for the @HasPaid parameter yet the method expects a `boolean` type (true/false) for hasPaid. Will the ADO.NET code take care of converting the `boolean` to a `bit` type for SQL Server or do I need to convert the value of `hasPaid` into a `1 or 0`?

```
public void UpdateClient(int clientId, bool hasPaid)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.myConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("uspUpdatePaymentStatus", conn))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", clientId);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HasPaid", hasPaid);
            sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
            var rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should do the conversion for you

Comment: It should but be careful with the AddWithValue as it can exhibit some weird behavior, you're better off declaring the types explicitly

Comment: .NET will take care of this for you. SQL Server will implicitly convert most junk that resembles a Boolean type to bit, so this will be no exception.

Comment: @Dustin - I have tried it and it seems to work but I was wondering if this is the best way to do it or should I pass in `1 or 0`

Comment: @webworm - got you.  I've always used boolean parameters this way and had no issues.

Comment: Here is an article discussing the issues with AddWithValue as @bumble_bee_tuna was mentioning. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 12):

When working with SQL parameters I find `AddWithValue`'s auto detection feature of the type too unreliable. I find it better to just call `Add` a explicitly set the type, `Add` also returns the new parameter it creates from the function call so you can just call `.Value` on it afterward.

```
public void UpdateClient(int clientId, bool hasPaid)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.myConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("uspUpdatePaymentStatus", conn))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = clientId;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@HasPaid", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = hasPaid;
            sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
            var rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the correct type is doubly important when using stored procedures and it is expecting a specific type, I just got in to the habit of always doing it this way.

Comment: but shouldn't a Bit Parameter accept 0 or 1?  It only accepts Boolean.

Comment: @MikeW it only shows up as 0 or 1 in Sql Management Studio because that's how they wanted to display it. It actually is a Boolean value.

Comment: a Bit is 0 or 1 but if you do:  sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@HasPaid", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1; you wil get an error when you Execute.

Answer (score 0):

Just Convert Bool to int before sending in EF Queury
`Convert.ToInt16(boolValue);`